# adding seaborn regplot ax to subplot python

Tags: python, plot

I am trying to add regplot to my subplots (other plots was added without problem).
I get an empty plot with few dots in the middle (regular plot gives me a good plot).

what is the problem?

```
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows = 1,ncols= 2, sharey=False,sharex=False)
.
.
.
.

sns.regplot('x1', 'x2',
            data=df, fit_reg=False, ax=ax1)

plt.show()
```